# Why Mongodb crash after inserting?

Tags: mongodb, fatal-error

I know the question is asked before.But the answers did not touch me.

```
Deleted record list corrupted in bucket 18, link number 9, invalid link is 1788887572:6aa04074, throwing Fatal Assertion
    Tue Jan 21 16:55:52.168 [conn1]  xxx.activity Fatal Assertion 16469
```

The answers were about `the data file was corrupted`What does it mean ?Why is this happenning? How can i avoid this error without loosing any data and without stopping the db?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MongoDB data files have internal structure necessary for the server to read and understand the data. Somehow, your data files were altered so the internal structure isn't correct and MongoDB can't work with them. It's very difficult to tell how this happened without a lot of information about what was going on in the system. You need to repair the database files. This requires shutting off the mongod and restarting it with the --repair option, as the best first thing to try. This will essentially rebuild your data files and try to fix any problems as best as possible.

Comment: I'd like to add that for forensic analysis a copy of the datafiles should be made prior to recovering the data.

Comment: Does '--repair' cause the old data that not corrupted destroy ?